# Doctrine not creating auto UUID

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm having a trouble. When I perform an persist() and flush() in Symfony, I'm getting this:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO pedido (emissao,
>   total, cliente_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["2018-01-10",
>   "100.00", "65c4002a-06e2-442b-b1da-61197f73ba3b"]: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

My annotation is the same in all entities, but in this one (specifically), Doctrine can not create auto id:

```
/**
 * @var \Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="uuid", unique=true)
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
 * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="Ramsey\Uuid\Doctrine\UuidGenerator")
 */
protected $id;
```

As the field ID is generated automatically, this error appears to make no sense. I have others entities like Pessoa which works fine with the same annotation.

How can I force Doctrine to "understand" the UUID index?

Comment: Is there any other property with ID generator in this entity?

Comment: Yep, there is a "codigo" (code). But is an autoincrement generator (int), not an UUID.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Currenly Doctrine does not support more than one autogenerated field in single entity. If there are 2 fields Doctrine will generate value for the last one and left first field with default value (`null` if not specified).

Since Ramsey uses static methods to generate UUID you should place it's generation where persistent logic is (manager, handler or whatever) or inside entity's constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->uuid = Uuid::uuid4()->toString();
}
```

And remove corresponding annotations:

```
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
* @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="Ramsey\Uuid\Doctrine\UuidGenerator")
```

**Another solution**

Since your second column uses auto increment feature of database (I assume you are using MySQL) you can try to:

1. Remove generator annotations on this column
2. Define column definition (non-portable and hacky IMHO) manually with `AUTO_INCREMENT` option:

   1. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#column
   2. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: The second solution works better. I've tried to create a class to generate the autoID, but was executing some queries to get the last ID and this makes no sense :P
Thank you!

Comment: Is it save to do the uuid generation manually in the constructor? What happens if a entity is loaded from db (with existing uuid)? Do I need a public setter method for the uuid field then?

Comment: Constructor is not called if an entity is loaded from db.

Answer (score -1):

You need to:

1. check, that field `id` in table `pedido` is autoincremented primary key.
2. change `VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)` to `VALUES (?, ?, ?)` becouse you insert only 3 values

Comment: It is a UUID generator, not an auto incrementor :/